# iOS 7 using an HTML string as an NSAttributedString AND setting the font?

Tags: ios7, uitextview, nsattributedstring, textkit

I have a UITextView in which I'm trying to display some attributed text which comes in the form of HTML. It uses things like inline bolding and italicizing. The client now wants the font on this to change. However, whenever I change the font, it seems to disregard any of the HTML formatting. Is there any way to change the font while retaining the other formatting attributes, like bolding an italicizing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I was able to get it to work was to prepend my string with `<span style=\"font-family: Avenir; font-size: 12\">%@</span>`

Answer (score 1):

For an objective-c approach, I used `NSMutableString` and `-setAttributes:`

```
NSString *htmlString = @"..."
NSData *textData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
      initWithData:textData
           options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
[attrStr setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"avenir" size:12.0f]} range:NSMakeRange(0,attrStr.length)];
```