# Apply Custom font to Attributed string Which Converts from HTML String

Tags: html, ios, ios7, nsattributedstring

I used `UITextView` in which i display `NSAttributedString`. i got **HTML** string from server . I converted HTML to NSAttributedString using below code.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrib = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[strHTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,  NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

To Apply font i tried below 2 codes.

1. apply Attribute
2. Custom String

To Apply Attribute i use below code.

```
[attrib addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
          value:myFont
          range:NSMakeRange(0, attrib.length)];
```

For Custom String first i create below `NSString` and then covert in `NSAttributedString`

```
NSString *strHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: myFont; font-size: 12\">%@</span>",@"my string"];
```

Using both code Font changed successfully. but **Bold and Italic** not applied only **Underline** is applied in NSAttributedString.

i refer below links.

1. [iOS 7 using an HTML string as an NSAttributedString AND setting the font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318276/ios-7-using-an-html-string-as-an-nsattributedstring-and-setting-the-font)
2. [ios7 font size change when create nsattributedstring from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992950/ios7-font-size-change-when-create-nsattributedstring-from-html)
3. [How to add CSS of an html to NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090597/how-to-add-css-of-an-html-to-nsattributedstring)

for link 3 should i apply fonts and tags from server side and then retrieve HTML String?

Any Help would be appriciated !!!

Comment: If I remember correctly, the issue is that bold and italic effect are inside the `NSFontAttributeName`. There is no NSItalicAttributeName or NSBoldAttributeName. So a way to do it, is to enumerate the attributes and inspire you with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153156/find-attributes-from-attributed-string-that-user-typed/23153221#23153221

Comment: @Larme yes i tried my self and did same .:) . thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally i got answer. you can check larmes answer([Find attributes from attributed string that user typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153156/find-attributes-from-attributed-string-that-user-typed/23153221#23153221)) or you can simply remove old font attribute and apply new font using below code.

```
 NSDictionary *dictAttrib = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,  NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};
 NSMutableAttributedString *attrib = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithData:[yourHTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:dictAttrib documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
 [attrib beginEditing];
        [attrib enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrib.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
            if (value) {
                UIFont *oldFont = (UIFont *)value;
                NSLog(@"%@",oldFont.fontName);

                /*----- Remove old font attribute -----*/
                [attrib removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
                //replace your font with new.
                /*----- Add new font attribute -----*/
                if ([oldFont.fontName isEqualToString:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT"])
                    [attrib addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font1 range:range];
                else if([oldFont.fontName isEqualToString:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT"])
                    [attrib addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font2 range:range];
                else if([oldFont.fontName isEqualToString:@"TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT"])
                    [attrib addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font3 range:range];
                else if([oldFont.fontName isEqualToString:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT"])
                    [attrib addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font4 range:range];
                else
                    [attrib addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font5 range:range];
            }
        }];
[attrib endEditing];
```

Thanks. Maybe it will help you.