# NSFontAttributeName not applied to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm currently using this extension provided by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132610/5222077) to convert html to strings within a `UITextView`. Everything works perfectly but for some strange reason the `NSFontAttributeName` is not applied to the string during the process. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? (or should I apply the `NSAttributedString` after reeving the attributed html parsed string? If so, is it possible to apply an attribute to an `NSAttributeString`? ).

PS. Font size is not change when using `html2String` but the links within the html is are longer recognized by the `UITextView`

```
extension String {

    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard
            let data = dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
cell.desc.attributedText  = apiData[currentIndex].description!.html2AttributedString //Font attribute not recognized
cell.desc.text  = apiData[currentIndex].description!.html2String //Font recognized by links no longer recognized
```

Comment: That's normal behavior. `NSFontAttributeName` is not an allowed key for `options` parameter in `initWithData:options:documentsAttributes:error:`. You have to rewrite afterwards the font effect. So either you apply it by adding HTML into the original string, or afterwards (by that may remove the bold/italic effects).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply Custom font to Attributed string Which Converts from HTML String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401742/apply-custom-font-to-attributed-string-which-converts-from-html-string)

Comment: @Larme Thank you for these details, I had no idea this attribute was ignored in this method. I'm leaving my answer for OP in the case they decide to convert like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* (probably because of having a range) but it works if you first create an NSMutableAttributedString and then you add the UIFont attributes:

```
extension String {

    var html2AttributedString: NSMutableAttributedString? {
        guard
            let data = dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            else { return nil }
        do {
            let attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil)
            attrStr.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17.0)], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length))
            return attrStr
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String {
        return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: A little warning: If there is bold or italic effect in the HTML part, setting the font like this will remove it (since it's in the `UIFont`/`NSFontAttributeName` part). Reason why it's not working is because `NSFontAttributeName` is not a valid key (and ignored) in that init method.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks Eric! @Larme I will not be setting any bold or italic effects, this answer suits my needs. Thanks for the information

Comment: @kye You're welcome. :) and thanks again Larme for the additional infos.

Comment: @EricAya works perfectly. Thank you for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here i have updated to **SWIFT 3**

```
extension String {

    var utf8Data: Data? {
        return data(using: .utf8)
    }
}

extension Data {
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white,NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }

    var attributedStringHtml: NSMutableAttributedString? {
        do {
         let   attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: self, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
            attrStr.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length))
            return attrStr
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let attribut = self.sampleText.utf8Data?.attributedStringHtml
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.convertedTextLbl.attributedText = attribut
            }
        }
```