# Converting HTML Tag to String

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I want to convert `HTML Tag` to `String`, I used `enum` to find the content length of the `String`, according to the length i need to do some operations.

My `modal` class,

```
class PostViewModel {
    var content: TextContent
    enum TextContent {
            case expanded(String)
            case collapsed(String)

            static func == (lhs: TextContent, rhs: TextContent) -> Bool {
                switch lhs {
                case .collapsed(let content):
                    if case collapsed(content) = rhs {
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                case .expanded(let content):
                    if case expanded(content) = rhs {
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And i am calling this function in `cellForItem(at index: Int)`,

```
func applyVerticalSizeConcernedRendering(fromViewModel viewModel: PostViewModel) {
    switch viewModel.content {
        case .collapsed(let content):
            let str = content.html2String
            print(str)
        case .expanded(let content):
            break
    }
}
```

`html2String` is `extension` class of `String`

```
extension String {
      var html2AttributedString: NSMutableAttributedString? {
      guard let data = data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return nil }
            let attrs: [String: Any] = [
                NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
            ]
            do {
                let attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: attrs, documentAttributes: nil)
                return attrStr
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return  nil
            }
        }
        var html2String: String {
            return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
        }
    }
```

The problem is it's crashing while converting HTML tag to `String`

It's crashing here,

```
let attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: attrs, documentAttributes: nil)
```

**And the `String` is not empty**

Below is the example `HTML String`,

```
<strong>I want to test HTML Tags<br><\/strong>dsfhjdjf sjdfdj  djfjdfj djkf dfjdhf <strong>adjf<br>asks <\/strong>djfdkf<br><strong>dfdjk dkfjdk <\/strong>dfjik iai <strong>adsfhj<\/strong>
```

This is working fine when i tried with hardcode value, but it's crashing only when i get the `String` from the `enum`

[image: And i don't know why the <code>String</code> is placed inside brackets. I hope, that's causing the crash]

The crash log is,

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint and check on which line exactly it fails?

Comment: @TMob I edited in the question, where it's exactly crashed

Comment: is there any chance that the HTML string you are trying to convert is empty?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I am 100% sure, that's not empty

Comment: can you add it to the question? so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: @MilanNosáľ edited it to the question, can you able to reproduce the crash?

Comment: I mean can you add an example of the HTML that you are trying to convert (of course, the shorter the better)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSFontAttributeName not applied to NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427442/nsfontattributename-not-applied-to-nsattributedstring)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Edited the question

Comment: @karthikeyan I am not using 'NSFontAttributeName'

Comment: remove that alone

Comment: that code works.. however, the HTML example there is not valid HTML, what are those backslashes doing there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to Plain Text in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124119/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-swift)

Comment: I tried it with the enum too, and it still works. Show us how are you creating that instance of the TextContent (which you use in the switch).

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Can you please look into the image i attached, why is that `String` is inside the brackets?

Comment: Xcode shows it the same way in my case.. but I don't really know.. My last guess now is that there is a problem in a way that you initialize the enum instance.. in my testing I tried:

`let content: TextContent = .collapsed("<strong>I want to test HTML Tags<br></strong>")`

Comment: Please see the updated question, that's how i am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this instead, no need to do the whole process that you have done:

```
extension String {
    var htmlAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8), options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    var htmlString: String {
        return htmlAttributedString?.string ?? ""

}
```

**Usage:**

```
let html = "<strong>I want to test HTML Tags<br></strong>dsfhjdjf sjdfdj  djfjdfj djkf dfjdhf <strong>adjf<br>asks</strong>djfdkf<br><strong>dfdjk dkfjdk </strong>dfjik iai <strong>adsfhj</strong>"
let str = html.htmlString
```

So you basically just use the `String extension` on your Strings. This is what I use in my projects

**Update:**
The above prints the following:
[image]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2a9b4jqqtzf9lf5/HtmlToString.zip?dl=0) is a example project that you can try.

Comment: Still crashes but with different crash log,

`-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000025be70`

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000025be70'`

Comment: That´s weird. Checkout my update of what my code prints out and I have also added a sample project that you can try.

Comment: Please see the updated question, it's working fine with hard coded values

Comment: Even I had crashes : Exception NSException * "*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]" 0x0000600002ae8240
But when I put the code in main thread  DispatchQueue.main.async {
it worked for me . I had though the issue was due to conversion.